# How to give permission to group to read/edit unowned files on archlinux?

Tags: files, permissions, arch-linux, chmod

I'd like to be able to read files from external hdd or other partitions without having to `su root` every time or chmod the whole partition to myself/group. How can I give myself/group permission to read files that are owned by root **and** are outside of the `/` file system?

The external drive has NTFS and ext4 file systems, which are being automounted by `dolphin`.

Maybe there is a way to auto assign additional group for files not in `/`?

Comment: A lot of filesystems will let you specify a `user=` mount option for setting ownership to a non-root user. Is that the sort of solution you're looking for? What type of filesystem is on the external HDD?

Comment: What do you mean by "files that have no owner"? Can you give us a sample `ls -l` for one of those files?

Comment: By unowned I meant not assigned to any user by myself, but from `ls -l` on external partitions I see they have user `root` which looks like was automatically assigned. That is bad since I'd need to know a difference between my own system `/` for which I have root user and the rest of the system that does not belong to it. Maybe there is a way to auto assign additional group for files not in `/`?

Comment: What filesystem is on the external drive? How are you mounting it? This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)...

Comment: ntfs and ext4, automount by `dolphin` (I retrieved `ls -l` by manually `mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/foo`) and hopefully I'm still sticking to X - reading files (with user/group) that are owned by root and are outside of my os.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option `user` `users` or `group` while mountig will do it:

`mount /dev/sdx /<mountpoint> -o user=<myuser>` or simmilar with the other options.